# How to know if the pipe is empty -- WIN32

Tags: winapi, ipc, pipe

I'm writing a program that communicate with its child process using anonymous pipe. And I want to know if there are contents in the pipe for me to read. Because calling `ReadFile` for an empty pipe would result in halting.

The child process is another software so I can't change it. I can only redirect its i/o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PeekNamedPipe` function to examine the state of the pipe without blocking.